# Access is denied to the path C: WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to write and read file.rdl to make report in wpf c#, but there is an error "Access is denied to the path c:\Document and Setting\SipusProv\Temp\reportTemp.rdl.
This is my source code:

```
private void LaporanRdl(string rdl, DataSet data, string judul)
    {

        DataSet dt = data;
        dt.DataSetName= "Data";
        Masaddy.Reprot report = new Masaddy.Reprot();
        try
        {

            //System.IO.StreamReader strReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\rdl\" + rdl + ".rdl");
            System.IO.StreamReader strReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\rdl\" + rdl + ".rdl");
            string pathTemp = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Temp\reportTemp.rdl";
            System.IO.StreamWriter strWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathTemp);

        string strIsi = "";
        while (strIsi != "</Report>")
        {

            strIsi = strReader.ReadLine().Trim();
            if (strIsi == "<Value>txtDep</Value>")
            {
                strIsi = "        <Value>" + this.ddDeputi.SelectedItem.ToString() + "</Value>";

            }
            if (strIsi == "<Value>txtDir</Value>")
            {
                strIsi = "        <Value>" + this.ddDir.SelectedItem.ToString() + "</Value>";

            }
            if (strIsi == "<Value>txtSubDir</Value>")
            {
                strIsi = "        <Value>" + this.ddSubDir.SelectedItem.ToString() + "</Value>";

            }
            if (strIsi == "<Value>txtTahun</Value>")
            {
                strIsi = "        <Value>" + this.txtTahun.Text.ToString() + "</Value>";

            }
            strWriter.WriteLine(strIsi);
        }
        strWriter.Dispose();
        Masaddy.ReportForm r = new Masaddy.ReportForm(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\\Temp\\reportTemp.rdl", "Data", dt.Tables[0]);
        r.Text = judul;
        r.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which version of windows you are using?

Comment: Well? Did you check the permissions? Is the file open in another process? Is the file read-only? What have you checked so far?

Comment: Also, totally unrelated to your question, you may want to look into the wonderful `System.Path` class (particularly the [`Combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) method).

Comment: Seems like there's a question here. Not sure what though...

Comment: And you have double escaped slashes (once with the `@` raw string literal, and once with extra backslashes) in the `Masaddy.ReportForm()` call near the bottom. And your stream is never closed if an exception is thrown (that's what [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is for).

Answer (score 1):

"Access denied" means exactly what it says. The real questions are

- What user is your code running as?
- What resources are affected by the failing operation?
- What permissions does that user normally have on each of those resources?
- Is UAC coming into play?

It's no good asking the rest of the world why permissions are as they are on your specific system. Only you are in a position to investigate that.

This "question" gives me a terrible urge to say "plz send me teh configz".

Answer (score -1):

i think u run program under Windows Vista/7
try to use Application Manifest file

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <!-- UAC Manifest Options
        If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
        requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

        Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
        If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
        compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
    -->
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```